# Unable to open Jupyter Notebook installed in VM, says could not locate runnable browser

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Jupyter Notebook in my VM located in OpenStack. A token is generated, but it's unable to open in the browser. What I am missing in the installation or some paths are incorrect?

[image]

Comment: Please try to upload error messages too as a a text, it makes it easier to answer. Also if you haven't already please take a look at how to ask awesome questions here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Jupyter notebook needs a browser on the system its running on. Your VM doesn't have a browser installed. The error message says it all.